# Question marks just started appearing in PDF files created from HTML using ABCpdf

Tags: asp.net, html, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a web based application (ASP.NET 2.0) on a virtual dedicated Windows Server 2003 SP2 box, that converts HTML forms and converts them to PDF using ABCpdf.  It has been around for years, and hasn't been changed for at least the last two of those years.

Three days ago it started placing question marks throughout the outputed PDF documents.

The question marks seem to correspond with empty span tags in the HTML. Any ideas on why this might be happening, or what I might need to do to resolve it?

UPDATE ------------

The html is generated via xsl and immediately used to generate a pdf.

I did, in fact, have the character   in the positions where the question mark was appearing.  However, since this is a way of encoding a non-blanking space, all I could see in the html was a blank space (even when turning on see all symbols in notepad++).

When I replace the   instances in the xsl code with a simple space character, the question marks went away.

Note: I was also able to make the question marks disappear from the final pdf by using charset="iso-2022-jp"  However, the intermediate html showed Japanese characters.

Comment: Seeing the HTML code in question might be helpful. Also, are you using special characters? ÄEÖÜóÌ....

Comment: No special characters.  The span tags look like this:  <span style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 5px;"> </span>

Comment: Try some debugging to see what happens when. If you remove the span, what then? Are you sure there's nothing in it? Not even a space? What happens when you put in a character? What if you change span to div?

Comment: If someone can enlighten me as to why several years of using the same exact xsl with &#xA0; characters now no longer works, I'd be happy to mark as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ABCpdf uses the IE engine from the machine to load and render the html. Have you updated the IE browser version on the machine? For sure it's something related to the IE browser (since you say you made no changes to your xsl / html).

Thanks,
Flores